# Many ping request timed out occurs when many concurrent connections

Tags: windows, .net

I run my own app server made in .net 4.0 on a Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.
When the number of concurrent connections (clients online) reach about ~7500-8000 users. The whole server become slowly/laggy with many ping time out request. If I drawn off the number of clients online on the server to 5000-6000, the server become normally with no packet timeout. That is quite strange because the CPU usage and the bandwidth still free a lot. CPU usage only take 30% when it reach 8000 clients online, and the bandwidth only take 100 Mbps of 200 Mbps available. Is it a software problem or hardware problem or network problem, how can I troubleshoot for this case?

Comment: I'd try mirroring the port and look for NAKs.  I'd initially bet on network congestion at the port.

Comment: @JimB Hi JimB, thank you very much for trying to help me. Since I'm a programmer, I don't know much about network and NAKs. If it's a network congestion at the port, what should I can do? Should I buy more IP address so it will transfer users to other IP & port?

Comment: You are going to need someone with networking experience because you should also look for how many active ports are open. If you have used up all free ports then responses have to wait. If you have used too much bandwidth, again you’ll have to wait to send s response.